# ag-grid StopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus conflict with the select

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I customized a drop-down box and added ag-custom-component-popup, but it still didn't stop the mouse click from losing focus。

Reference example：

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-neduxw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprop-editor%2Fprop-editor.component.ts

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-date/#example-custom-date

```html
<nz-select
  #nzSelect
  [(ngModel)]="singleValue"
  nzSize="small"
  [nzDisabled]="!isEdit"
  [nzDropdownMatchSelectWidth]="false"
  nzAllowClear
  nzShowSearch
  [nzFilterOption]="nzFilterOption"
  style="width: 100%"
  class="ag-custom-component-popup"
>
  <nz-option
    (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
    nzCustomContent
    *ngFor="let _typeData of _typeData"
    [nzValue]="_typeData.id"
    [nzLabel]="_typeData.name"
  >
    <span> {{ _typeData.id }} . {{ _typeData.name }} </span>
  </nz-option>
</nz-select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiW2A.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzAIY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE7T7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0pZ5.png)